# Universal Image Loader not loading image for specific link

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I started to use Universal Image Loader instead of Picasso, to avoid the image-not-loading problem. Now it emerges in Universal Image Loader too. It is the same problem with the same unique image, but not other images.

The problematic Image:

http://luxproperty.kaytami.com/platform/media/image/jpeg/2015/01/4_4.jpg

Other properly-behaved images:

http://luxproperty.kaytami.com/platform/media/image/jpeg/2015/01/4.2_4.jpg

http://luxproperty.kaytami.com/platform/media/image/jpeg/2015/01/4.3_4.jpg

http://luxproperty.kaytami.com/platform/media/image/jpeg/2015/01/4.4_4.jpg

They are of similar sizes. And about my Universal Image Loader, the setting is as such:

In Application:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024) // 50 Mb
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
        .build();
// Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

In activity:

```
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_error)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.image_error)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .build();

    .......

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url), image, options);
```

Any hints would be much appreciated. I just cannot get rid of this problem anyhow, neither with Picasso nor Universal Image Loader.....

My previous StackOverFlow with Picasso:

[Picasso cannot load images for some URL (no special characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426468/picasso-cannot-load-images-for-some-url-no-special-characters)

Comment: You are blaming Picasso and Universal Image Loader. But is this fair? They only download that image and assign it to an ImageView. I think the image view refuses that picture. Or a bitmap factory that is used. Find out by putting the picture on your device and then in a image view with the usual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the image is corrupted as downloading and opening it in photoshop also throws error. You can also see the bottom part of the image for blurry pixels.

Although there is one more case that I know of when image loading fails is when loading an image in CMYK color format. Android doesn't support CMYK, although there are some Third-party libraries for loading CMYK images but I don't think that it is the case for you. I strongly believe that the image is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the blurry pixels too. Maybe that is the cause. The problem only occurs for this image but not any others, so I think this reason is quite convincing.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    prova = context;

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    //.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(1000))
    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder) 
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true)
    .considerExifParams(true)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    //  .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(70))//////
    .build();
```

//note you use this in your adapter where your handling your image and make sure you inistalize  that your UIL class in your manifest application

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.UILApplication"
```

Comment: I changed the bitmapConfig and it is still not working.

Comment: check with your UIL and make sure that your UIL is 1.9.3